# List contents of ZIP file using ZipKit

Tags: cocoa, zip, nstableview

I need to get list contents of ZIP file using ZipKit framework. The content I want to present in NSTableView. So, ideally I need to get NS(Mutable)Array. Is there a simple way how to do this ?

Thanks a lot, Petr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be honest I think that you should use [Zipzap](https://github.com/pixelglow/zipzap) for working with zip files. It's a very good library. I've used it and I don't have anything bad to say about it.
Take a look at the github page and there's some example snippets for you to test out.